# "git svn fetch" leads to "RA layer request failed"

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I just ran

```
git svn fetch
```

and got

> RA layer request failed

How can I resume the `fetch`?

Comment: Have you tried resuming by doing `git svn fetch` again? :-)

Comment: i tried svn fetch again, but it didn't work  gave same error.
I changed the protocol from http to svn and it worked. thanx for response

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your svn repository is corrupt? If you do an svn checkout from that repository and perform an svn cleanup?